# What are good non-bicycling exercises with a knee injury?

Tags: injury, exercise

I banged up my knee in an accident and I won't be able to bicycle for a few months.  I'd like to keep up my cardio and calorie burning as much as possible during my time off.  What kinds of things can I do at the gym or home to try to replicate what biking gives me?  I will of course need things to do that don't involve my knee too much.

I can swim, but don't have access to a pool now. I can use my knee a bit. I have even gone biking. But, even a small ride (about twenty miles) will result in knee pain and weakness for days, up to a week.

Comment: How much can you not use your knee? can you swim? can you walk? Hand cycling is a good option too.

Comment: @BenjaminBerry: I can swim, but don't have access to a pool now.  I can use my knee a bit.  I have even gone biking.  But, even a small ride (about twenty miles) will result in knee pain and weakness for days, up to a week.

Comment: @Neil Fein: Other stackexchange sites have big-list as a tag for such questions.  Is there something akin to that here?

Comment: The edit definitely helps. Perhaps limit it further by adding something like "exercises that will help me stay in shape for bicycling when I return to it"? Or am I missing the intent?

Comment: @NeilFein: I think "cardio and calorie burning" is reasonably specific about the intent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Since I know nothing about the knee injury, I am considering your lower body out of the picture for working out.)

Take this as an opportunity to work the hell out of your upper body. Do pull-ups, chin-ups, push-ups, Hindu push-ups, bench presses, overhead presses, handstands, handstand push-ups, dips. Buy or make a sandbag and practice throwing and heaving it around.

If you specifically want "cardio", try making a circuit routine out of a few of these (for instance, alternating between a pushing and pulling exercises) and do a set number of rounds or a set amount of time.

Answer (score 4):

Swimming won't give you a 1:1 to biking (obviously) but it works out your whole body implicitly and is a great overall cardio workout and a **great** place to get started.

Otherwise I would take a look at spinning, low resistance.